# How to connect Android Emulator with desktop via Serial Port?

Tags: android, android-emulator, serial-port, adb

I have a simulator application where I send serial commands to an Android device and vice-versa. In order to work with this application, I need to connect a real Android device via physical RS232 cable and then select the device.

My question is, is there a way to create a virtual serial port connection between the emulator and Mac/Linux PC?

I've seen commands like `emulator *emulator-name* -qemu -serial /dev/ttyS0`, but I get an error message

```
qemu-system-i386: -serial /dev/ttyS0: 'serial' is not a valid char driver name
qemu-system-i386: -serial /dev/ttyS0: could not connect serial device to character backend '/dev/ttyS0'
```

Comment: _"I need to connect a real Android device via physical RS232 cable"_ You have an Android device that has a RS232? A real RS232, not USB?

Comment: @Fildor yes, I have a specialized tablet with two RS232 ports, but the interface is not important, I'll take any way to make that connection

Comment: Looking into this myself.  For one, it seems the `/dev/` path might be a red herring.  [This post](https://kashyapc.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/qemu-command-line-behavior-of-serial-stdio-vs-serial-monstdio/) is using `stdio`.