# Cannot connect Android emulator to a virtual serial port

Tags: android, android-emulator, serial-port, virtualization

I have a virtual serial port installed on my Windows 10 system, which sets up a bridge between virtual ports named COM2 and COM3. I wrote a test application *for desktop* to see whether the bridge works and there was no problem. The data sent from COM2 was correctly received in COM3. So the ports seem to be fine.

Now I want to run the android emulator connected to one of these virtual ports. The command I wrote is this:

```
emulator.exe -avd android6 -partition-size 512 -qemu -serial COM2
```

First, the configuration panel for the serial port appeared:

[image: port configuration]

but after confirming the port config, the following error message appears and the emulator never starts:

```
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\..\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe: -serial COM2: Failed SetCommState
c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\..\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe: -serial COM2: could not connect serial device to character backend 'COM2'
```

Now the irony is, if I change `COM2` to `COM1` which is an *actual* serial port, the emulator starts without any problems and connects to that port after showing the port-configuration window. So I think the issue here has something to do with `COM2` being *virtual*.

I tried everything I could and searched fruitlessly for hours to figure out what's wrong, which led to nothing useful (including [this totally irrelevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65181461/5358284))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I found out that some virtual port software just don't support connecting to the emulator. After that I installed the Virtual Serial Port Driver by [Eltima](https://www.eltima.com/products/vspdxp) and it just works fine.

DISCLAIMER: This is not a promotion and I don't have any kind of affiliation with Eltima. I added the answer only because it might save some others from a lot of trouble and headache. The only valid conclusion from this answer is Eltima's software works with emulator, while others seemingly don't function properly.